# unique in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

I have been trying to run this code with oracle 11g and an error occur all the time which is 'ORA-00936: missing expression' I think the problem is with unique clause but I don't know why.
any ideas please ?

```
select id , name , dept_name , salary
from instructor 
where unique (select teaches.id
              from teaches 
              where instructor.id = teaches.id and year = 2009 );
```

Comment: What tutorial/doc are you following that states UNIQUE is an operator like EXISTS or ANY
 in Oracle? Curious because I've only ever known it to be a keyword in creating contraints/indexes etc

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am learning it at collage, I want to find the instructors who has thought only one course in 2009

Comment: Please pass in where clause `where unique (select distinct  teaches.id
              from teaches 
              where instructor.id = teaches.id and year = 2009 ); `

Comment: @APC, `where unique` specific query condition I don't think so `unique()` function working in where query.

Comment: @jishansiddique - no it doesn't work, that's why the Seeker gets ORA-00936. So I don't understand what you're trying to say with your comment. Adding DISTINCT in the subquery won't make UNIQUE() any more valid as Oracle syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
        select distinct id , name , dept_name , salary
```

And you where should be a "In" statement that

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want instructors that teached only once in 2009.

If so, you could do:

```
select id, name, dept_name, salary
from instructor i
where (select count(*) from teaches t where i.id = t.instructor_id and t.year = 2009) = 1;
```

I would expect that the `teaches` table has an `instructor_id` column rather than `id` to relate to `instructor(id)`.

Another option uses aggregation:

```
select i.id, i.name, i.dept_name, i.salary
from instructor i
inner join teaches t on t.instructor_id = i.id and t.year = 2009
group by i.id, i.name, i.dept_name, i.salary
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: you are right but I need to try it with unique clause

Comment: @programmer: there is no `unique` clause in Oracle; `unique` can be used in the definition of indexes, that's about it. You can see other answers and comments mention that too.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of what you want to do, as well as sample data would certainly help; all we know is that you wrote a query which is invalid.

Meanwhile, yet another lucky guess:

```
select i.id, i.name, i.dept_name, i.salary
from instructor i join teaches t on t.id = i.id
where t.year = 2009
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I need to try it with unique clause"

UNIQUE is **not** an operator. What you can do is this:

```
select id , name , dept_name , salary
from instructor 
where instructor.id in  (select unique teaches.id
                         from teaches 
                         where   year = 2009 
                         group by teaches.id having count(*) = 1);
```

However, the UNIQUE is redundant because this has the same effect:

```
select id , name , dept_name , salary
from instructor 
where instructor.id in  (select teaches.id
                         from teaches 
                         where   year = 2009 
                         group by teaches.id having count(*) = 1 );
```

---

If you're not happy with the answers we've given you need to post a link or a quote from the tutorial. Because it seems like you're trying to do something which the Oracle SQL syntax does not support.